# Difference in working of arrow function and anonymous function within constructor

Tags: javascript, callback, anonymous-function, arrow-functions

My original code was like this:

```js
function Person() {
  this.age = 0;
  console.log(this.age);
  setInterval(function() {
    this.age++;
    console.log(this.age);
  }, 1000);
}

let p = new Person();
```

The output was something like this:

```
0
NaN
NaN
.
.
.
```

But when I changed the callback function to an arrow function it worked:

```js
function Person() {
  this.age = 0;
  console.log(this.age);
  setInterval(() => {
    this.age++;
    console.log(this.age);
  }, 1000);
}

let p = new Person();
```

This time the output was:

```
0
1
2
3
.
.
.
```

The anonymous function couldn't access the constructor variable. Why so?

Comment: You can do something like this : function Person() {
var self = this;
this.age = 0;
console.log(this.age);
setInterval(function() {self.age++; console.log(self.age);}, 1000);
}

Comment: Wow, I didn't know there was a workaround like this. Thanks